# Intersection of Pandas two dataframe with almost have same column except one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, inner-join

tab1 having column name as: `'index', 'Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Date', 'Recovered'`

tab2 having column name as: `'index', 'Province/State', 'Country/Region', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Date', 'Confirmed'`

due to missing values in both the table so, I want to join these unordered (46550 × 6 and 44275 × 6) tables on common lat and long values. I tried merging join but failed to accomplish the results.

Comment: can you show your attempt? I think you need to do a union of both the tables. please read [mcve] and [ask] and add some sample data with an expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you need "intersection", so I guess you need a inner join.

```
df = tab1.merge(tab2, how='inner', on=['Lat', 'Long'])
```

After this, you may have other columns duplicated because your dataframes have almost same columns as you claimed.

For example, you will have `Province/State_x` from `tab1` and `Province/State_y` from `tab2`. You will need to drop these duplicated columns:

```
# E.g.
df.drop(columns=['Province/State_y'])
```

You probably also want to rename them back:

```
# E.g.
df.rename(columns={'Province/State_x': 'Province/State'})
```

Comment: @ShubhamRawatShubhi, if my answer worked, would you mind accept my answer so we can close this, please? Thanks